# Instead of date some random numbers are displaying when a date is retrieving from oracle database

Tags: jquery, ajax, oracle

My Oracle database table contains some dates like 25-FEB-15, when i retrieve this date using an Ajax call i am getting some numbers instead of exact date which is stored in the database.

Example

When i select 25-FEB-15 i am getting "1424802600000"

Ajax function

```
$.ajax({

                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                        dataType:'json',
                        url: 'invoiceregistration',
                        data: JSON.stringify(vendor_quotation_id),
                        success: function(result)
                        {

                            console.log(result)
                             if(result!=''){
                     $.each(result, function(i, item) {
                     alert(item)
                      });

                        }
                       });
```

Comment: Looks like you're getting a [Unix timestamp](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time).

Comment: @Biffen My OS is windows 7

Comment: It may very well be, but it still looks like you're getting a Unix timestamp (in milliseconds, by the look of it). It's a common format for storing dates and times, and most datetime libraries can make use of it, including JavaScript's built-in `Date`, in both [`setTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setTime) and [`getTime()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/getTime).

Comment: @Biffen can i convert it into correct format?

Comment: I don't know what the ‘correct format’ format is, but most likely yes.

Comment: @Biffen I want to display it as 25-02-2015

Comment: There are plenty of resources on the web, many here on Stack Overflow, on how to format a date in JavaScript.

Comment: use @JsonFormat(pattern="yyyy-MM-dd")  on top of public String hireDate; in Json File, Please refer  here https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-formatting-json-dates